# Java: Erro na Classe Connection

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, conexão, jframe

Como corrigir este erro ? Isto esta impedindo de conectar ao banco....

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Eventoos do Botao inserir
    try {
        //Registra JDBC driver
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //Abrindo a conexão: ATENÇÃO OS DOIS PARÂMETROS VAZIOS("") SÃO USUÁRIO E SENHA, RESPECTIVAMENTE.
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escola?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "", "");

        //Executa a query de inserção
        java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO aluno (id,nome,cpf) VALUES ("
                + this.jTextFieldId.getText() + ",'"
                + this.jTextFieldNome.getText() + "','"
                + this.jTextFieldCPF.getText() + "')");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Aluno inserido");
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
    }//Fim try
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi. Qual é o erro?

Comment: esta sublinhado em linha vermelha e não esta conectando ao banco...

Comment: sua IDE não fala o erro que está na linha?

Comment: sim...:cannot find symbol.  Symbol class: class Connection. Location JFrameAluno

Comment: Ao meu ver, está faltando você adicionar a `lib (.jar)` do seu banco de dados ao seu projeto, para que ele encontre estas classes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Solucionado...basta apenas importar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado. Basta importar:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
// Eventoos do Botao inserir
try {
    //Registra JDBC driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //Abrindo a conexão: ATENÇÃO OS DOIS PARÂMETROS VAZIOS("") SÃO USUÁRIO E SENHA, RESPECTIVAMENTE.
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escola?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "usuario_banco", "senha_banco");

    //Executa a query de inserção
    //java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    //st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO aluno (id,nome,cpf) VALUES (" + this.jTextFieldId.getText() + ",'"+ this.jTextFieldNome.getText() + "','"+ this.jTextFieldCPF.getText() + "')");

    PreparedStatement pstmStatement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO aluno  VALUES  ( ? , ?  , ? ) ");// id , nome, cpf 

    pstmStatement.setInt(1, this.jTextFieldId.getText() ); //this.jTextFieldId.getText()

    pstmStatement.setString(2, this.jTextFieldNome.getText() ); // this.jTextFieldNome.getText()

    pstmStatement.setString(3,  this.jTextFieldCPF.getText() ); // this.jTextFieldCPF.getText()

    pstmStatement.executeUpdate(); //executa o SQL 


    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Aluno inserido");//

} catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);

}//Fim try
```

}